# Using regular expression with PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file with multiple expressions like `$REGX('CareMedic.2_0','CustomerInformation','Customer Information')`. The file can be an xml file, text file or any other type. If the file contains nine of those expressions, I'm trying to pull all nine.

I've written my code as below:

```
$input_path = ‘C:\Users\rparpani\Desktop\test2.xml’
$output_file = 'C:\Users\rparpani\Desktop\test2.text'
$regex = '\$REGX'
$output = select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file

Write-Output($output)
```

Something seems to be wrong with my regex expression. Can someone please suggest the right way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you need to escape the $ (\$) in your regex otherwise it asserts the position at the end of the line

Comment: I tried doing that but it does not pull any values. If the file has 9 of the REGX expressions, I expect to pull them all.

Comment: @Itchydon Any suggestions?

Comment: If you run the code as far as -allmatches - what do you get?  When I try your code it works for me.  I have only tried with a txt file not with an xml

Comment: @Itchydon it writes to my txt file but it is just $RESX. I have to pull values between (). Once those values are extracted, I have to strip them apart and store it in 3 different columns

Comment: How about if you run up to -allmatches only - do you get the correct values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209333/discussion-between-raj-parpani-and-itchydon).

Comment: I have updated the code on chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` is a metacharacter in regex, meaning "end of string", so if you're looking for the literal string `$RESX`, you need to escape `$`:

```
$regex = '\$REGX'
```

You can also have it escaped automatically:

```
$regex = [regex]::Escape('$REGX')
```

Comment: I tried changing that but it does not appear to pull any values

Comment: In the example in your post it says "$RE**G**X", but in the code you use "$RE**S**X", typo perhaps?

Comment: It was a typo. I corrected it